# Why my microservices did not see a properties in Spring Cloud?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I recently work with Spring Cloud and I bumped with problem!
When I am trying to start my microservice I've got an error which looks like this:

```
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: {"timestamp":1565359011628,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError","message":"org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Class;)V","path":"/roomservices/dev"}
```

My main module pom.xml (parent pom for cloud and working microservices):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.training.mainmodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>mainmodule</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>config</module>
        <module>room-services</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Edgware.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Working microservice bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: roomservices
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:9000
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

And pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
            <groupId>com.training.mainmodule</groupId>
            <artifactId>mainmodule</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

        <groupId>com.training.roomservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>room-services</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Cloud application yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: classpath:/shared
  profiles:
    active: native

server:
  port: 9000
```

Working microservice(which called roomservices) config in cloud microservice roomservices.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      dll-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
        show_sql: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: root
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring
```

Structure of my project looks like this:

[image]

Its looks like my roomservice cannot find properties in cloud. What did I miss and how it can be fixed?

Comment: path":"/roomservices/dev  while your /roomservices/dev is located under map shared ?

Comment: Edgware and versions 2.x of spring cloud libs are not compatible. You should remove versions from `spring-cloud-starter-*` and let the maven bom manage it. Greenwich.SR2 is the latest that supports 2.x. Edgware.SR6 is the last to support boot 1.5.x but that has reached end of life (EOL).